# Clickable TableRow on Android

Tags: java, android, tablerow

I have a simple program i have made in java for android but am having difficulty in making the tablerow clickable. When the user clicks a row i wish for a certain picture to be displayed in the imageview below. Here is my xml code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF909090"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="I" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="A"
            android:onClick="Achord" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="II" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="Bm" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="III" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="C#m" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />

    <TableRow android:background="#0000ff" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="IV" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="D" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="V" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="E" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="VI" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="F#m" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="VII" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="G#dim" />
    </TableRow>




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:text="The relative minor of the Major key of A is F#m. The 12 bar blues progression in A is: \n A | A | A | A | D | D | A | A | E | D | A | E" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:src="@drawable/android_focused" />
```

and here is my java code:

```
package com.coreservlets.widgets;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import com.welly.keychords.R;





 public class keya extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.keya);
}
}
```

what i want to happen is that imageview1 will display a different image depending on what row is clicked. Any help would be greatly appreciated

As sam suggested i have ammended my code to this:

```
public class keya extends Activity {

    ImageView imagev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.keya);
    }

    public void rowClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.one:
            // Load image from Drawable folder
            imagev.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_normal); // example file for now
            break;
        }
    }
   }
```

but now i have a null pointer exception on running that class. all compiles fine though

Answer (score 3):

Simply give each TableRow element a unique `id` and define an `onClick` method:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:onClick="rowClick">
```

Add a class variable `imageView` that references the ImageView in your layout. Then load the image:

```
public void rowClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.one:
        // Load image from Drawable folder
        imageView.setImageResource(R.id.imageOne);
        break;
    }
}
```

Understand that any elements inside a TableRow with their own `onClick` method will call its own method. For instance the TextView with `android:onClick="Achord"` will call `Achord()` not `rowClick()`.

---

**Addition**
You need to call `findViewById()` *after* declaring your layout with `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`.

```
ImageView imagev;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.keya);
    imagev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
}
```

Comment: i have changed my code to this:                                  public class keya extends Activity {
ImageView imagev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.keya);
    }
    public void rowClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.one:
             imagev.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_normal);
            break;
        }
    }
   } but have nullpointer exception on run

Comment: please see my edited first post sam as the comment box doesnt like code

Comment: Yea, comments have minimal markup features. Thanks for adding the code to your question, I hope the update makes the answer clear.

Answer (score 2):

Give each row an ID, then you can assign a listener to each one in your code:

```
TableRow row = (TableRow)findViewById( R.id.row1 );
row.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v ) {
        //Do Stuff
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call setOnClickListener() for each of your TableRow objects so that framework knows what to do when a row is clicked.  In addition your Activity should implement View.OnClickListener() so that you can control what happens when a row gets clicked.  Right now you aren't doing anything when the View gets clicked; at least according to your code you aren't registering a callback on any of the Views' onClickListeners

Answer (score 0):

Assign id to Tablerow just like row1

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF909090"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="I" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="A"
                android:onClick="Achord" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="II" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Bm" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="III" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="C#m" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TableRow android:background="#0000ff" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="IV" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="D" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="V" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="E" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="VI" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="F#m" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="VII" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="G#dim" />
        </TableRow>




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:text="The relative minor of the Major key of A is F#m. The 12 bar blues progression in A is: \n A | A | A | A | D | D | A | A | E | D | A | E" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.03" />
        </TableLayout>
```

Call it in activity like this.

```
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.TableRow;
        import com.welly.keychords.R;

        public class keya extends Activity {
            TableRow row1;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.keya);
        row1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.row1);
                row1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.e("Click ", "Row 1");
                    }
                });

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it working by declaring the imageview variable within the public void rowclick

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign an id to Tablerow in xml layout file:

   ```
    <TableRow
           android:id="@+id/rowL1"
           ...
    </TableRow>
   ```
2. Add the following in your java file:

   ```
   private TableRow rowL1;  

   //In onCreateView...
   rowL1 = (TableRow) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rowL1);
   rowL1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
       //Your code here...
   });
   ```